# Which exception should be thrown?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I wrote a custom action method selector attribute that has three `bool` properties. It's invalid for all three of them to be `false`. At least one of them has to be `true`. When `IsValidForRequest` gets executed I check that at least one of them is `true`. But if none is, which exception should I throw?

Some relevant code:

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public bool Prop1 { get; set; }
    public bool Prop2 { get; set; }
    public bool Prop3 { get; set; }

    public MyCustomAttribute()
    {
        this.Prop1 = true;
        this.Prop2 = true;
        this.Prop3 = true;
    }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        }

        // at least one of them must be true
        if (!this.Prop1 && !this.Prop2 && !this.Prop3)
        {
            throw new ?????
        }

        // other codez here
    }
}
```

Attributes have this nice ability of initializing them while also providing property values, so I have to check them in the `IsValidForRequest` method.

```
[MyCustom(Prop1 = false, Prop2 = false, Prop3 = false)]
```

### Which exception should be thrown?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd probably throw `InvalidOperationException`, because the operation is not valid for the object's current state.

Comment: I was more into some sort of `InvalidObjectStateException` if there was any... but `InvalidOperationException` seems fine. Let's see if there're any other ideas.

Comment: This is the exception used most often by the .NET library, in cases like this (see SerialPort.ReadChar when port not open, for example).

Comment: I'd also go with `InvalidOperationException`, though every time I use it, I always wonder if there's anything better!

Answer (score -1):

You could try with [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) if those properties got loaded from user input... or you could implement your own [custom exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229064.aspx) to throw.

It really depends on how those properties got set.

Comment: As per my example. They're not set by means of constructor parameters. My constructor is parameterless because I don't need parameters actually.

Comment: `ArgumentException` shouldn't be used unless the problem lies with an argument to the current method. "The exception that is thrown when one of the arguments provided to a method is not valid."

Comment: Yes but I actually meant if they came from user input or are calculated fields or something else. The type of the exception gives the programmer (and subsequently the user) an idea of the context the problem arose in. So what do the properties mean is important to throw the right exception type.

Answer (score -2):

Throw an exception with your specific custom message using

```
throw new Exception("Custom Error Message");
```

Comment: Throwing base-class Exception is not recommended. If you want to go that route, declare and throw a custom exception.